# getting "undefined" when trying to get timesince to update automatically on a chat app with javascript

Tags: javascript

still getting undefined, tried moving things here and there but still not working. the function works fine when removing the setinterval but as before doesn't update automatically. the function from top to bottom is as follows:

```
function drawMessage(message) {
    let position = 'left';
    
    
  function timeSince() {
     setInterval(showTimeSince, 1000);
           }
    
   function showTimeSince(){
     const date = new Date(message.timestamp);
     var seconds = Math.floor((Date.now() - date) / 1000);
     if (Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25)) >= 2) _time = Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25)) + " years ago";
.... rest here as suggested... .. = "1 minute ago";
     else if (seconds >= 2) _time = seconds + " seconds ago";
     else _time = seconds + "1 second ago";
    
      console.log(_time)
    }
    
     var aDay = 24*60*60*1000;
     console.log(timeSince(new Date(Date.now()-aDay)));
     console.log(timeSince(new Date(Date.now()-aDay*2)));
    
  if (message.user === currentUser) position = 'right';
        const messageItem = `
    
                <div class="message ${position}">
                <span class="small">${timeSince()}</span><br>
                        <div class="text_wrapper">
                          <div class="text">${message.body}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`;
        $(messageItem).appendTo('#messages');
    }
```

need support. am unable to get it to work. maybe a small detail that i am missing since I am new to Javascript.

Comment: I bet message is not defined inside the scope of your interval, so message.timestamp is thereby also undefined.

Comment: Most likely the problem is you are returning in setInterval but you cant do that. Instead you need to call a function from within the interval that actually does something with the time.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is you are returning in setInterval but you cant do that. Instead you need to work with the string in the callback or call another function to do it for you.

In my answer, I'm calling a function instead of using the anonymous function because it is cleaner.

```
    function timeSince() {
      setInterval(showTimeSince, 1000);
    }

function showTimeSince(){
        const date = new Date(message.timestamp);
        var seconds = Math.floor((Date.now() - date) / 1000);
      if (Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25)) >= 2) _time = Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25)) + " years ago";
      else if (Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25)) >= 1) _time = "1 year ago";
      else if (Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 30.4)) >= 2) _time = Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 30.4)) + " months ago";
      else if (Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 30.4)) >= 1) _time = "1 month ago";
      else if (Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)) >= 2) _time = Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)) + " weeks ago";
      else if (Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)) >= 1) _time = "1 week ago";
      else if (Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)) >= 2) _time = Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)) + " days ago";
      else if (Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)) >= 1) _time = "1 day ago";
      else if (Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60)) >= 2) _time = Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60)) + " hours ago";
      else if (Math.round(seconds / (60 * 60)) >= 1) _time = "1 hour ago";
      else if (Math.round(seconds / 60) >= 2) _time = Math.round(seconds / 60) + " minutes ago";
      else if (Math.round(seconds / 60) >= 1) _time = "1 minute ago";
      else if (seconds >= 2) _time = seconds + " seconds ago";
      else _time = seconds + "1 second ago";
    
      console.log(_time)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found a half solution. I had to insert the setInterval under the function that calls the function under which sits the timesince function. Now the whole thing updates after the interval i set and not just the time, but setting an update interval of 1 minute makes it fine with me.
Apparently since I have several functions under one, the setInterval doesn't work, or didn't work in my case.

this:

```
function getConversation(recipient) {
  setInterval(function(){
    $.getJSON(`/api/v1/message/?target=${recipient}`, function (data) {
        messageList.children('.message').remove();
        for (let i = data['results'].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            drawMessage(data['results'][i]);
        }

        messageList.animate({scrollTop: messageList.prop('scrollHeight')});
    });

}, 60000);}
```

or this:

```
function getConversation(recipient) {
    $.getJSON(`/api/v1/message/?target=${recipient}`, function (data) {
        messageList.children('.message').remove();
        for (let i = data['results'].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            drawMessage(data['results'][i]);
        }
        **setInterval(getConversation(recipient), 1000);**
        messageList.animate({scrollTop: messageList.prop('scrollHeight')});
    });

}
```

Thank you David and Imvain2